# Sorting algorithms with respect to type of data being sorted

Tags: .net, algorithm, sorting

I have an .NET interview coming up tomorrow and I realized that I'm kind of weak on my algorithmic side (otherwise I'm exceptionally good programmer maybe better then you ...  haha, joke, who laughed ?) as I've never programmed any mathematically intense algorithms at my job.

I was wondering what algoritms are best suited/most performant for sorting data of certain types? For example, what algorithm would you use to sort two lists of `DateTime` in ascending order? No LINQ allowed here, so that you sort them fastest?

And similarly, what algoritms are best suited for sorting other types of data, like strings or numbers, etc.?

Comment: Seems to me that one of the benefits of being a .NET programmer is you don't have to write "mathematically intense algorithms" anymore, at least not for simple, everyday tasks like *sorting*. There are lots of other questions here about sorting algorithms; nothing about this is unique to .NET, other than perhaps the freedom to forget what it's like to re-implement the wheel each time.

Comment: Yep, seems to me too, until 2 years ago when I was looking for a job again and I used 'List.Sort()' method like a normal person would do and didn't get the job:) So I'd like to be more prepared this time just in case I get hit with a similar coding task

Comment: Did they actually tell you that using a built-in method in the Framework was the reason that you didn't get the job? I think you dodged a bullet there. Thank your lucky stars you're not working for a company with Not Invented Here syndrome...

Comment: I don't know how much detail the OP wants, but there are specialized (faster than O(n lg n)) sorting algorithms when the keys are integers or floating-point numbers in a small range, or other specialized things that have operations beyond just comparison.

Comment: @Cody Gray: No, it was a top 500 employeer

Comment: @Jeremiah Willcock: Yes that's what I like to know faster as far as O(...) goes. Thanks! Please help:)

Comment: @Simio: How does that disagree with anything I just said? I don't know what a "top 500 employer" is, but I don't think that's enough to make it a very desirable work environment, assuming you "failed" the interview by using one of the BCL sorting functions instead of rolling your own. If I were hiring, and a potential candidate wasted a bunch of time writing a sorting method of his/her own without a *darn* good reason, that would be sufficient reason for me *not* to hire them.

Comment: @Simio: I don't really feel like writing up a long answer right now, so someone else will need to get the reputation points for it.  The place to start is probably the "Non-comparison sorts" table on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm and the two lists starting with "Additionally, theoretical computer scientists have detailed" and "Algorithms not yet compared above" below the tables, plus the "distribution sorts" line in the table of sorting algorithms at the end of the page.  There is also a list of variants of bucket sort at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bucket_sort.

Comment: @Cody: The issue could be that the employer wanted somebody who could write a sorting algorithm if they had to (i.e., knew how they worked); I would hope that they would see the person using the standard algorithm and then suggest that, for the interview, they should write it by hand, though.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jeremiah Willcock! I'll read up on it.

Comment: @Cody: Sorry, maybe you are right:) I just felt like more was needed the question seemed to easy to be true: It said precisly that here is 2 datatime list sort & merge them so I did. top 500 employeers are the biggest/best employeers rated by a bunch of magazines

Answer (score 1):

There are different sorting algorithms, but you can use any of them regardless of the data type, you just need a method to compare two values and determine if they are the same or if one of them is larger than the other.

There are ready made sorting algorithms in the framework, for example the `List.Sort` method. If you are sorting a list of simple values (like strings, numbers, dates, et.c.) that is already supported as there are default comparers for those:

```
myList.Sort();
```

If you are sorting custom objects, you can provide a comparer to the method:

```
myList.Sort((x, y) => x.Name.CompareTo(y.Name));
```

If you want to implement a sorting algoritm yourself, you can look at different ones like insert sort, merge sort, quick sort, shell sort, et.c. One of the simplest ones to understand and implement is [bubble sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort).

Comment: Thanks Guffa I thought so too since everything translates to a number eventually - its comparable. So do you know any fast algoritms that can be aplied in the rare case that you should do when a typical Linq or for loop doesn't cut it ?

Comment: Gah! Bubble sort! <runs and hides>

Answer (score 1):

Most sorting algorithms are designed around the idea that comparing data elements is a primitive operation (that is, it's not part of the algorithm design). There are exceptions, though (like radix sort).

More interesting is the question of what algorithm is best suited for specific assumptions about the input: is it mostly sorted already; does it all fit in memory without severe performance problems; do tied elements need to stay in their input order; does external data need to be correlated with the sort; etc.

If I were preparing for an interview, I'd bone up on the latter issues. (But I wouldn't want to do it the night before :). Good luck on your interview.)

Comment: Thanks for your wishes Ted! This type of issues I've faced so I think I may be ok here but good point I'll reveiew these now.